# How re-enter output data from a function back into a function

Tags: python

```
def play(player_1_skill, player_1_strength,player_2_skill,player_2_strength,divider,skillmod,strengthmod):
    strengthmod = math.floor((abs(player_1_strength - player_2_strength))/divider)
    skillmod = math.floor((abs(player_1_skill - player_2_skill))/divider)
    die_p1 = r.randint(1,6)
    die_p2 = r.randint(1,6)
    if player_1_strength > player_2_strength:
        print("Player 1 Wins")
        player_1_strength = strengthmod + player_1_strength
        player_1_skill = skillmod + player_1_skill
        player_2_strength = player_2_strength - strengthmod
        player_2_skill = player_2_skill - skillmod
    elif player_2_strength > player_1_strength:
        print("Player 2 Wins")
        player_2_strength = strengthmod + player_2_strength
        player_2_skill = skillmod + player_2_skill
        player_1_strength = player_1_strength - strengthmod
        player_1_skill = player_1_skill - skillmod
    else:
        print("Tie")

    print("The skill modifier : "+ str(skillmod))
    print("The strength modifier: " + str(strengthmod))
    print("Player 1, Your strength is: " + str(player_1_strength))
    print("Player 1, Your skill is: " + str(player_1_skill))
    print("Player 2, Your strength is: " + str(player_2_strength))
    print("Player 2 , Your skill is: " + str(player_2_skill))





    return (player_1_strength, player_1_skill, player_2_strength, player_2_skill,skillmod,strengthmod)



play(player_1_skill, player_1_strength,player_2_skill, player_2_strength,divider,skillmod,strengthmod)
play(player_1_skill, player_1_strength,player_2_skill, player_2_strength,divider,skillmod,strengthmod)
```

How do I repeat a function using different data from the same function
eg function outputs data, output data back into function

Comment: Capture the return values into variables and pass the variables into the next function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to put these data into or dictionaries.

Example with dictionaries:

```
def play(player_1, player_2, divider):
    # access the individual values like:
    player_1['strength'] = ...something...
    ...something... = player_2['skill'] / divider

# then

player_1 = {
    'strength': 10,
    'skill': 20,
}
player_2 = {
    'strength': 15,
    'skill': 16,
}

play(player_1, player_2)
```

Now the function `play` can modify the values inside the dictionaries you're passing.